# How can I give permissions based on user to Views in jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, permissions, view

I want to give Admin privileges to one user who can see one View  but all others should not be able to see that View.Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Matrix-based security](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Matrix-based+security)

by using this you can restrict access for each users.